# How to use simple_form and formtastic (active_admin) side by side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, formtastic

I have a rails project, which uses the active_admin gem. This active_admin depends on the formtastic gem. However, I want to use simple_form instead of formtastic in my app (in all parts outside active_admin).

The problem: simple_form and formtastic both declare the "simple_form_for" helper and in general have a very similar DSL.

How can I use simple_form in my app, while still keeping active_admin (with its formtastic) around?

If you ask yourself, why I need such a troublesome setup: I use twitter bootstrap and simple_form supports bootstrap nicely, while formtastic does not.

Comment: To my knowledge, formtastic (at least 2.2.1+) doesn't define a simple_form_for method, it defines semantic_form_for method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that nowadays *(2015+)*, the simplest and the most proper way to ensure `SimpleForm`'s compatibility with `Formtastic` (including the `ActiveAdmin` dependency) is to wrap your custom `SimpleForm` inputs in a *namespace*:

```
# If needed, you can namespace your custom inputs in a module and tell `SimpleForm`
# to look for their definitions in this module. This can avoid conflicts with other
# form libraries (like `Formtastic`) that look up the global context to find inputs
# definition too.

# app/inputs/custom_inputs/numeric_input.rb
module CustomInputs
  class NumericInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::NumericInput
    def input_html_classes
      super.push 'no-spinner'
    end
  end
end


# config/initializers/simple_form.rb
config.custom_inputs_namespaces << 'CustomInputs'
```

Check the [Custom Inputs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#user-content-custom-inputs) section of the `SimpleForm` [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, good idea! I will try it, once such a problem occurs again. For now I solved my problem by getting rid of ActiveAdmin and using a combination of rails_admin (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) and intercom.io. I had no similar issues with these two solutions yet.

Comment: That's how we've resolved similar issue, yep, it sucks to stuff all my inputs in namespace just for sake of active_admin working. I would rather prefer it other way around.